# How to group orders based on their numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe(df_orderlines) which is grouping several products by their OrderNumber. I am trying to create a wave for the picker to pick up this products. I managed to do it if it's only 1 order at a time but i would like to do this dynamically. How can I do this? Currently I have this.

```
    if (orders_number == 1 ):
        df_orderlines['WaveID'] = df_orderlines.OrderID.fillna(0).astype(int) - 1
    else:
        for i in range(orders_number):
            df_orderlines['WaveID'] = (df_orderlines.OrderID % orders_number == 0).shift(1).fillna(0).cumsum()
```

it outputs a dataframe like this when 2 orders are being picked at the same time

| OrderNumber | TimeStamp | Coord | OrderID | WaveID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-11-02 12:00 | 0,7 | 1.0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2019-11-02 12:00 | 1,8 | 1.0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2019-11-02 12:00 | 0,8 | 1.0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2019-11-02 12:10 | 3,10 | 2.0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2019-11-02 12:10 | 2,9 | 2.0 | 1 |
| 3 | 2019-11-02 12:20 | 5,24 | 3.0 | 2 |
| 3 | 2019-11-02 12:20 | 2,12 | 3.0 | 2 |
| 3 | 2019-11-02 12:20 | 3,43 | 3.0 | 2 |
| 4 | 2019-11-02 12:30 | 6,24 | 4.0 | 2 |
| 4 | 2019-11-02 12:30 | 3,30 | 4.0 | 3 |

But instead it should look like this

| OrderNumber | TimeStamp | Coord | OrderID | WaveID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2019-11-02 12:00 | 0,7 | 1.0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2019-11-02 12:00 | 1,8 | 1.0 | 0 |
| 1 | 2019-11-02 12:00 | 0,8 | 1.0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2019-11-02 12:10 | 3,10 | 2.0 | 0 |
| 2 | 2019-11-02 12:10 | 2,9 | 2.0 | 0 |
| 3 | 2019-11-02 12:20 | 5,24 | 3.0 | 1 |
| 3 | 2019-11-02 12:20 | 2,12 | 3.0 | 1 |
| 3 | 2019-11-02 12:20 | 3,43 | 3.0 | 1 |
| 4 | 2019-11-02 12:30 | 6,24 | 4.0 | 1 |
| 4 | 2019-11-02 12:30 | 3,30 | 4.0 | 1 |

Comment: Can you provide a dataframe sample ?

Comment: I am using a .txt file with data I created just for testing. The initial dataframe should look like this

OrderNumber | TimeStamp | Coord|


The data is already on the question

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do it, probably not the most eficient way but it does the job.

```
    if (orders_number == 1 ):
        df_orderlines['WaveID'] = df_orderlines.OrderID.fillna(0).astype(int) - 1
    else:
       df_orderlines['WaveID'] = ((df_orderlines.OrderID + (orders_number-1)) // orders_number) - (orders_number-(orders_number -1))
```